# How to response for wrong passed parameter in Apiary?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I saw the following Action section inside of Apiary blueprint examples. I want to response with HTTP status 404 when the user passes a wrong parameter. for example when the user passes /questions/xyz instead of /questions/1.
As you can see we defined that the parameter after /questions must be a number but when I passed xyz itstead of a number it answer with a same object.

```
## Questions [/questions/{question_id}]
An Questions object has the following attributes:

+ question - We can put some description for each attribute here.
+ published_at - An ISO8601 date when the question was published.
+ url (string) 
+ choices - An array of Choice objects.

+ Parameters
    + question_id: `1` (number, required) - ID of the Questions in form of an integer

### View an Questions Detail [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/json)

            {
                "question": "Favourite programming language?",
                "published_at": "2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z",
                "url": "/questions/1",
                "choices": [
                    {   <!-- First Object -->
                        "choice": "Swift",
                        "url": "/questions/1/choices/1",
                        "votes": 2048
                    }
                ]
            }

+ Response 404 (text/plain)

    There is no such a message for the passed id. For example if you pass 'xyz' we expect to show this message.
```

Please write me complete code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [tag:apiary] [tag:apiary.io]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry but unfortunately Apiary doesn't yet support conditional responses based on the body and parameters that are passed in a request.